# request.post in Node throws { code: undefined, reason: 'Argument error, options.body.' }

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am getting the following error when trying to perform a `request.post`. It's confusing because it seems to be first referring to the `body` of my options but then complains about the first argument should be a string or buffer.

`{ code: undefined, reason: 'Argument error, options.body.' }
DOH!
_http_outgoing.js:454
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
          ^
TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer`

I tried changing the `url` value to a string but that doesn't fix it.

Here is what my code looks like. As you can see I've logged out the `reqOptions` and have verified that the url is definitely being passed to the `request.post`so I am not sure what the problem is. Cheers for any help!

```
var reqOptions = {
    url: options.host, 
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  };
  console.log('CHECK OPTIONS :: ', reqOptions); 
  request.post(reqOptions, function (err, resp) {...}
```

Comment: try `JSON.stringify(formData)` instead of just `formData`

Comment: If `formData` is an object, the [`body:` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) expects that its value is already prepared/formatted into a string/buffer. Try using [`form:`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#forms) instead to have `request` format the object as URL-encoded.

Comment: Cheers for quick response. You are correct, changing the `body` key to `form` did get rid of the error. Do you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `formData` is an object, you'll probably want to use `request`'s [`form:` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#requestoptions-callback) instead of `body:`. That will both stringify the object and set the `Content-Type` header.

```
var reqOptions = {
  url: options.host, 
  form: formData
};
console.log('CHECK OPTIONS :: ', reqOptions);
request.post(reqOptions, function (err, resp) {...});
```

---

The `body:` option expects a value that is either a string, Buffer, or ReadStream. Without using `form:`, you'll have to stringify the object yourself.

```
var qs = require('querystring');

var reqOptions = {
  url: options.host, 
  form: qs.stringify(formData),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add json : true

```
  request({
    url : url,
    method :"POST",
    headers : {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    body: body,
    json: true
},
```